# show message log in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

How to show message log in **console** when executing test cases from the console? RIDE can show message log when executing tests but I don't know how to set it in command line options. I looked up the command line options but I didn't find such an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [robot logging api](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#programmatic-logging-apis) instead to log to console. Here is an example from the documentation:

```py
from robot.api import logger

def my_keyword(arg):
    logger.console('Hello, console!')
```

You can use the BuiltIn Keyword `Log To Console`. 
Here are some examples from [the Documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log%20To%20Console)

```
Log To Console   Hello, console!    
Log To Console   Hello, stderr!               STDERR
Log To Console   Message starts here and is   no_newline=true
Log To Console   continued without newline.
```

Both will be printed to the stdout during test execution.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a listener that behaves similarly to RIDE's listener.

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface-methods

Robot Framework has a `--listener` command line option you could use to have your listener active during a run.

Answer (score 0):

under `C:\Users\GARA\AppData\Roaming\RobotFramework\ride\settings.cfg` enable `log_to_file`

```
[[Log]]
log_to_file = True
log_to_console = True
```